# verificar numeros sequenciais visualg

Tags: c, visualg

Tenho um vetor q vai ser preenchido por 6 valores aleatórios e preciso verificar se 
existe numeros em sequencia no vetor. Como faria isso ?

Comment: Como assim em sequência? Por exemplo: 0 ,1 ,2 ,3 ...

Comment: isso mesmo 0,1,2,3...

Comment: Caso estejam em sequência o que deve ser feito?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa noite, vc pode depois de atribuir o valor random, comparar pra ver se o anterior + 1 é igual

```
for(int i = 0; i<6; i++)
{
    //Nao lembro como usar o rand em c mas acho que e assim
    vetor[i] = rand();
    if((i>0) && ((vetor[i-1]+1) == vetor[i]))
    {
        printf("número sequencial");
    }
}
printf("nenhum numero sequencial");
```

Dessa forma vc consegue pegar sequências como 14579(4 e 5 sequencial)
Aquela verificação do i>0 é porque se ele for 0 ele vai virar um -1 na outra condição e iria dar erro no vetor
Foi mal eu ter feito em c, mas se vc conseguir entender a lógica é a mesma.
Boa sorte aí, espero ter ajudado

Comment: Para isto funcionar você precisa ordenar o vetor antes de fazer a verificação.